# Ayuda con el diseño de un botón en HTML

Tags: html, botón, diseño

**Buenas hoy vengo porque necesito saber cual código que se utiliza para cambiar una imagen cuando se pone el mouse sobre ella y como le hago para aplicarlo al clásico botón de los formularios.**

```
<input class="botons" type="submit" value="Login">
```

Comment: Trata de explicar mejor tu duda por favor, lee [ask]

Comment: Falta información detallada y mas clara a tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Si tu botón tiene 200px * 50px por ejemplo, y quieres que tenga una imagen que cambie al hacer hover... lo primero es hacer la imagen con ambos estados, un ejemplo...

- Boton: 200px * 50px.
- Alto de imagen para usar: 200px * `100px`.
- Debes poner la imagen del estado normal del boton en los primeros.
- 50px del alto de la imagen. El estado hover en desde los 51px de la
  imagen hacia abajo. Ambas imágenes deben estar distribuidas para que
  encajen en los 200px * 50px.

luego:

```
.botons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('ruta de tu imagen');
  background-position: top;
}
.botons:hover {
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

Lógicamente debes quitar el `"Login"` del `value`, y resetear los valores css por de fault que trae el `input` tipo `submit`, como el borde, background, etc. Puedes usar dos imágenes diferentes para el mismo efecto, pero esto haría un salto raro a la primera carga del hover.

Comment: Es mejor esperar a que el OP provea un mejor contexto pues a la pregunta le faltan muchos detalles